# The "right" way to combine Vue (frontend), Python (backend API) and Okta (authentication)

Tags: okta

I'd like to build a web app using Vue for the frontend, and Python (Flask or FastAPI) for backend API calls.

Both on the frontend and the backend, I'd like to have authentication via Okta in place.

I'm able both to create a frontend (I used Okta cli for the boilerplate) with the desired protection in place, and a backend (using Flask-OIDC). However, I'm not sure how to plug those two together: is it sufficient to protect the API calls and trust that the user will be logged in through the frontend? Do I need to protect both the frontend and the backend (I strongly believe: yes)? I'm sure there is some sort of best-practice out there, but I fail to find it; would be very grateful for any pointers in the right direction.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be fine with your approach: frontend will obtain an access_token from Okta, which you will be sending to your backend, where it should be verified appropriately.

Another architecture, which can be utilized, is establishing your own session by your backend (some sort of traditional web-client app), if you are only planning to have your front-end talking to your backend. It can be easily done with traditional authorization_code flow, where server will have both client_id and client_secret parameters. This is described in more details on [Okta Developer](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/implement-auth-code/overview/) site.

I'm not familiar with Python frameworks, so can't help with examples, but I'm sure you can find some examples online.